# InvalidArgumentError: Input is empty

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am training a variational autoencoder as part of a college assignment but unfortunately I got stuck very early on.

I used the following code snippet to visualize the data set that I had downloaded.

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,5, figsize = (14,14))
    sample = training_dataset.unbatch().take(25)
    sample = [image for image in sample]

    idx = 0
    for row in range(5):  
        for column in range(5):
            axes[row, column].imshow(sample[idx])
            idx+=1
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input is empty.
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Any idea as to what is causing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Some sample input would be nice!